# json feed events: only calling controller when controller has no arguments

Tags: c#, json, fullcalendar

I am trying to implement json feeds FullCalendar.

If I use a signature for GetCalendarEvents with no arguments, the View calls the function.  If I use it with the start and end arguments, the function does not get called.  The only thing different that I can find in my code appreciable to the code in the sample is that they somehow get away with calling the script in the view without the header information I have to put in.

Header Code in View

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='~/Content/fullcalendar.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='~/Content/scheduler.css' />
<script src='~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js'></script>
<script src='~/Scripts/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='~/Scripts/moment.js'></script>
<script src='~/Scripts/scheduler.js'></script>
```

This works fine in  example code I downloaded from here.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/638674/Full-calendar-A-complete-web-diary-system-for-jQue

The following is the code in question.

View Code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectable: true,
        slotMinutes: 15,
        events: '/Calendar/GetCalendarEvents/'
        });
```

Controller Code

```
public JsonResult GetCalendarEvents(double start, double end)
    //public JsonResult GetCalendarEvents()
    {
        var fromDate = CalendarEvent.ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
        var toDate = CalendarEvent.ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

        var rslt = _orderService.Query(s => s.FromDate >= fromDate && s.ToDate <= toDate);

        List<CalendarEvent> result = new List<CalendarEvent>();
        CalendarEvent rec = new CalendarEvent();
        rec.ID = "lskfj1231";
        rec.title = "Testing";
        rec.start = "2016-01-17T12:00:00Z";
        rec.end = "2016-01-17T13:00:00Z";
        result.Add(rec);

        var eventList = from e in result
                        select new
                        {
                            id = e.ID,
                            title = e.title,
                            start = e.start,
                            end = e.end
                        };
        var rows = eventList.ToArray();            
        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted it out.  For reasons unknown (I will look into this at some point and update this solution) the sample project/solution sends a request to the controller for start and end arguments in unix time format.  My project/solution sends the request to the controller for start and end arguments in DateTime format.

I just modified my signature in the Calendar controller for GetCalendarEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end) and everything is great.

Thanks!

Comment: The example may have been written against fullcalendar v1.x In v2 it changed from start/end being unix timestamps to ISO 8601 format (ala moment.js). If you downloaded a later version of fullcalendar than was used in the demo project it may explain the difference in functionality. See [version 1 json documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/events_json_feed/) vs [version 2 json documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) sample URLs

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        data : {start : 11, end : 15}
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectable: true,
        slotMinutes: 15,
        events: '/Calendar/GetCalendarEvents/'
        });
```

You need to pass attributes in the data parameter

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply!  The sample code does not do this.  I'm not sure, but somehow it gathers the time in unix format and passes it into the json event stream call on the controller.  I gave this a try and it did not fix the problem.  -Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by two ways.

1) Event as a json feed

```
eventSources: [

        // your event source
        {
            url: '/Calendar/GetCalendarEvents/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                start: startDate,
                end: endDate
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            }
        }
    ]
```

2)  Event as a function

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Calendar/GetCalendarEvents/',
            data: {
                // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                start: start.unix(),
                end: end.unix()
            },
            success: function(events) {
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks!  According to the sample and the documentation on the fullcalendar.io website I should be able to do this without setting up an eventSource, right?

Comment: Yes, if you use event as a function, you do not have to set up eventSources. You can make your own customized ajax request in events as a function to get events from your server url.

Comment: Hi, I tried the eventSources as a potential work around - I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the example code that you downloaded this is handled in the fullcalendar.js file. Take a look the _fetchEventSource method() at line 984.

I think that this is where the dates are added into the controller method call. You could trace your code to see if it is running through the js file, but my guess is that you don't have this file included in the correct order so it isn't utilizing the methods in the fullcalendar.js file.

Comment: The example you reference uses the _Layout.cshtml to reference the scripts and bundles.

Comment: This looks like promising, I am testing this now.  This would not be surprising at all, since I had some trouble with script locations and installation.  I wasn't able to install the way the sample indicated, using the BundleConfig.cs etc.  I had to put the script references in my header of the view I rendered the Calendar in for the calendar to show up.

Comment: Re: _Layout.cshtml

I tried to mimic this with no success.  This is why I ended up putting the script references in my header file.  Perhaps this is part of the problem?

Comment: You are spot on, it does not go through the fetchAndRenderEvents in fullcalendar.js.  In fact the compiler seems to have some foresight for this, it tells me that the symbols haven't been loaded for this file when I put the breakpoint in.

Any advice how to narrow downt he problem.  It would be nice to figure out how to 'install' this FullCalendar the way it was done in the sample code.

Chris

Comment: It should still work if it is in the file for the view itself.  Just to double check, do you have the $('#calendar').fullCalendar() method inside of the $(document).ready(function{}); method call?

Comment: The other thing that you will want to be sure of is that your element on the page is named 'calendar'.  If there isn't an element in the view named calendar, then the javascript method will never be called.

Comment: Yes on both accounts.  Calling the @calendar with an id="calendar" in a div.  The calendar itself loads fine, it's the json stream not calling the controller when I have arguments in the signature for my method.

Comment: I debugged my control, that is the sample I downloaded.  The logic never goes through the fetch statement in there either.  So this is not the problem.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by adding a blank view and included the files in the same order that you did in the header, then including the $(document).ready script with the same  code that you have.  I am not sure where yours is not working, but if I think you should be able to find it if you step through your code. Do you get to the anything in the fullcalendar.js file?

Comment: So your code will execute the controller /home/getdiaryevents/ routine if the GetDiaryEvents has arguments such GetDiaryEvents(double start, double end) ?

Comment: This is where I am stumped, I cannot find the difference between the sample code I downloaded and my code to give me a reason why my code does not work the same way.

I'm not sure how to step through this code?  If I put a breakpoint in my view it doesn't get executed since it's a script, I suppose.  Where is a good place to put a breakpoint to step through this?

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the Index method in the HomeController.  Both the sample code (my control) and my code go through the same things, except when my code is done, the sample code goes into the GetDiaryEvents function like it should.

Comment: You can add a breakpoint in the JavaScript file (fullcalendar.js).  I started at line 118 and stepped through from there, but you shouldn't need to step through the whole thing.  If the file is being utilized properly, then it should make it to this first breakpoint.

Comment: If you are adding the date in manually then you will want it to be parameterized like so:
`year: 2018,
month: 4,  
date: 25
`

Comment: My line 118 of fullcalendar.js is a }

The date is only added manually as a proof of concept.  It is getting formatted by the return json function.  If I remove the arguments in my controller function it will execute just fine and add the event to the calendar and display it in my view.  

I am using the newest version - 2.6.0.  Is that what you are using?

Comment: I haven't found anywhere that get's executed in my fullcalendar.js to put a breakpoint.  I have no idea how to tell where the entry point is from the view, how does one know in this case?

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer to double check, but I believe that execution of fullCalendar method starts right after the comments at the top of the script.